# Prebid.js and Nextjs set-up

Tags: next.js, prebid.js

I'm trying to set-up prebid.js ( npm package ) with nextjs projec.

Following example from ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/prebid.js ) by extending webpack config in next.config.js:

```
let path = require("path")

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }) => {

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /.js$/,
      include: new RegExp(`\\${path.sep}prebid\\.js`),
      use: [
        {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: require("prebid.js/.babelrc.js"),
        },
      ],
    })

    return config
  },
}
```

after this while trying to import prebid.js facing this error:

```
import {getGlobal} from './prebidGlobal.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Same error accurs even without webpack set-up. SO most likely that is incorrect, anyone would know how to set-up this?

versions:
Nextjs "12.2.2"
React "^17.0.2"

fresh install, no additional libraries.

I can run `prebid.js` by importing external script. Or using pure react with `prebidjs`.
But doing that with `nextjs` does not work.

Comment: link to sandBox : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cranky-shannon-4po3y9?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A29%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A10%2C%22startColumn%22%3A29%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A10%7D%5D

Comment: were you able to solve?

Comment: with this approach, not.

Comment: How have you integrated prebid in nextjs ?

Comment: using cdn. something like this ( https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/basic-example.html )